# Online Calculator for Complex Calculus - path in. C z3(z 1− 1)2 dz; |z − 2| = 5tegrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, online-resources

Does anyone know of an online calculator/tool that allows you to calculate integrals in the complex number set **over a path?**

I've searched in the standard websites ([Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/), [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)) and none of them has this option for complex calculus (they do have, as it has been pointed out, regular integration in the complex plain, but none has an option to integrate over paths).

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can deal with complex numbers, in fact, it usually assumes that the variable can also be complex.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/complex-analysis/ (found by googling "Wolfram complex")

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/complex-numbers-calculator (found by googling "Symbolab complex")

Comment: Why is this being down voted?  It is a reasonable question in which the OP has shown some research effort.

Comment: @MarkViola I downvoted because it took about two seconds to find answers on Google, and these answers evidently refute the OP's claim.

Comment: @MarkViola The question would only make sense , if the given tools could not do complex calculus. But this is not the case.

Comment: when i was reviewing the question, i must have deleted the "over path" out of the question and made it clearer. I've added it now, this is what i meant to be asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram alpha sure can work with complex integrals. Here I'm integrating $e^{i \theta}$ with respect to $\theta$, between $0$ and $2 \pi$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Be%5E%28I+theta%29%2C%7Btheta%2C0%2C2*Pi%7D%5D